# Launch PyCharm Environment from Anaconda Navigator

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, conda

I am trying to make it possible to launch a PyCharm Environment from Anaconda-Navigator.

A correct solution would result in PyCharm showing up on the Anaconda Navigator Home, just like JupyterLab in the image below.

[image]

I know this is possible because, on a previous computer I had, the option was shown as an icon with "Install" in the navigator (just like it says for RStudio, etc.).

Comment: This might be helpful 
https://medium.com/@GalarnykMichael/setting-up-pycharm-with-anaconda-plus-installing-packages-windows-mac-db2b158bd8c

Comment: That tutorial does not involve anaconda navigator, which is where I want to launch PyCharm.

Comment: ok, let me see if i can help you.

Answer (score 0):

when you create new project you need to configure it on the python installed with anaconda
[image: create new project and configure its python]

Answer (score 0):

create a virtual environment in anaconda using command-prompt:

```
conda create -n envname python==3.8
```

This will create an environment. Now open the pycharm and set the interpretor environment to existing environment. There will be a list of environment select the anaconda env and create the project. it will automatically add the pycharm into the anaconda navigator.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/es4wu.png)

Answer (score 0):

Adding the directory path of Pycharm to the configuration of Anaconda Navigator may solve the problem.

Open the Anaconda Navigator, click "File" - "Preferences", add the directory path of Pycharm in the "Pycharm Pro path" or "Pycharm CE path", depending on your Pycharm type. The directory path here should be the whole directory, for example, "C:\Pycharm".

Wish it helps!